# Bold subscript in plot axis

Tags: plot, subscript

I have a subscript in one axis title which I want to have it in bold as the rest of the text. I am using this code:

plt.ylabel(r'PC$_{\rm SD}$ (A)', fontsize=22, fontweight='bold')

but this does not make the subscript part bold (see the plot). Any suggestion? Thanks!

I attach my plot here:
[see y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBtAx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

`plt.ylabel(r'PC$_{\rm \bf{SD}}$ (A)', fontsize=22, fontweight='bold')`

[image]